# How to draw a right triangle with GraphViz or others text diagram processors?

Tags: graphviz, diagram

I am studying mathematics. I need to draw a right triangle. I want to use GraphViz to do it, but the diagram is not good enough.

Comment: I write my document with AsciiDoctor. AsciiDoctor Diagram can support GraphViz in a document. I google it, AsciiDoctor supports LaTeX,  but it does not support Tikz. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Tikz is a LaTeX package.

Comment: graphviz is better suited for drawing directed graphs dynamically not diagrams.